# Mono library assert when starting application for profiling

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono

I have a Xamarin application that I am launching in debug from Visual Studio.
I have followed a Microsoft blog on enabling the mono profiler using :-

```
adb shell setprop debug.mono.profile log:calls
```

However, upon restarting the app I get this in the trace it exits:-

Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mono/profiler/log.c:558, condition `PROF_TLS_SET (thread)' not met

Can anyone help me identify what's missing and how to get the profiler running?

Comment: You can see everything about Mono/Xamarin went sparse after 2020, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ Time to migrate to .NET MAUI.